# Why am I getting "StreamingQueryResult cannot be cast ..." error?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm getting this error on the below line

```
User ret=(User)query.execute(username.toString());
```

Does `query.execute()` can only be cast into *List<>*?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult cannot be cast to com.lionpaw.User
    at com.lionpaw.UserJDOWrapper.getUserByUsername(UserJDOWrapper.java:33)
    at com.lionpaw.LionPawServlet.doGet(LionPawServlet.java:21)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
```

Answer (score 0):

Execution of a JDO query will return a type suitable for the query that was passed in. If it is a query of a candidate type then List. You don't mention your query, so no further answer is possible. Read the JDO spec and any decent JDO docs, such as http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/jdo/jdoql.html#result